# Why would a.php file open as if it were an html file, rather than execute?

Tags: php, forms, action

I have a .php file that I'm trying to execute. It's referred to in the 'action' part of an html form.

For some reason when the form submits it opens the .php file in the browser as if it were an html page (a blank one).

The .php file doesn't have anything out of the ordinary in it, but I'm not sure it's getting to the point of executing it anyway.

My opening form tag looks like this: `<form action="my_script.php" method="post">`

What am I missing?...

Comment: Do you have a webserver installed? Invoking a .php script from the local filesystem (check address bar for `file://`) is not going to work.

Comment: If instead you get a really blank page (view source), then raise `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` in the php.ini, or check the servers `error.log` for fatal errors.

Comment: Thanks @Mario, I worked out what was happening (see comments further down).

Comment: I just read this on php.net, which could be the problem: The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

Comment: Yes that was it. I entered an absolute url and it worked ok this time.

Answer (score 1):

In all likelihood your script is executing. By default, HTTP headers will be sent indicating that the script's content is HTML, hence that's how your browser will treat it. But if you don't actually send any output, it'll appear as a blank page.

If you want the form to do something but not open a new page, maybe you could use AJAX to submit the form data without leaving the page. Alternatively, you could just add at the end of the script

```
echo 'Finished :)';
```

so that you know it has gotten to the end, and presumably done something.

Comment: I had the same thought re. echoing something at the end and indeed it did - this helped me fix the problem (see my last comment above). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a form, your browser posts data to the URL specified by the `action` attribute, as part of the request for that page.

Your page at `my_script.php` should output some HTML.

---

**If** instead you see your PHP code when you view the source of this new page, then PHP is not configured to be parsed on the server.

Comment: Thanks @Brad. I can't see my php code, just a blank window. If I view source there's nothing there either, but then there shouldn't be anyway. The php script is supposed to set a cookie, and then send you back to the previous page using `header( "Location: $HTTP_REFERER" );`. That's all there is in there, but as I said, I'm not sure it's getting this far anyway - the script's not running, it's opening?...

Comment: @matt: if you get a blank window, then most likely there's a fatal error of some sort in your script, and your PHP has display_errors/error_reporting turned off so there's no error messages being shown.

Answer (score -1):

euh... php

Use: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/index.html instead of opening a html file directly in your browser.